# News system, update user data dynamically

Tags: php

I have a news system that is supposed to update user data dynamically if a user changes their profile. Here's the script.

```
$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  $query = "SELECT * FROM news";
  $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);



  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {
  $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
  $post = $row['post'];
  $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
  $query2 = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = $user_id";
  $data2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data2);
  echo '<div class="viewpost">';
  echo '<div class="vpside">';
    if(!empty($row['picture'])) {
    echo '<img class="pictest" src="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . $row['picture'] . '" alt="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . 'nopic.png' . '" />';
    }
  if(!empty($row['username'])) {
      echo '<p>UserName:<br />' . $row['username'] . '</p>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['rank'])) {
      echo '<p>Rank:<br />' . $row['rank'] . '</p>';
    }
  if(!empty($row['gender'])){
    echo '<p>Gender:<br /> ' . $row['gender'] . '</p>';
  } 
  echo '</div>';  

    if(!empty($title)) {
        echo'<h4><u>' .$title. ' in ' .$category. ' News Updates</u></h4>';
    }
      if(!empty($post)) {
      echo '<pre><p class="">' . $post. '</p></pre>';
    }
    echo '</div><br />'; 
    }
    echo'</div>';
```

I am not sure why it is not working, but I think it may be something with the loop. It is also only showing two out of three news posts. These two news posts were written by the same person, so I think that it may only be pulling one of the users in the loop.

Comment: You need to do a better job of describing your problem. How does it not work? What should the results be? What do you get? What have you done to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Your overwriting `$row` in your second call, change it to `$row2`, you should also look into `INNER JOIN` as you can accomplish this with only one MySQL call

Comment: The answer below works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an updated version for you using `INNER JOIN`

```
<?php 

    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
    $query = "SELECT news.title, news.post, news.category, user.picture, user.username, user.rank, user.gender FROM news INNER JOIN user ON user.user_id = news.user_id";
    $data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)) {

        echo '<div class="viewpost">';
        echo '<div class="vpside">';
        if(!empty($row['picture'])) {
            echo '<img class="pictest" src="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . $row['picture'] . '" alt="' . MM_UPLOADPATH . 'nopic.png' . '" />';
        }
        if(!empty($row['username'])) {
            echo '<p>UserName:<br />' . $row['username'] . '</p>';
        }
        if(!empty($row['rank'])) {
            echo '<p>Rank:<br />' . $row['rank'] . '</p>';
        }
        if(!empty($row['gender'])){
            echo '<p>Gender:<br /> ' . $row['gender'] . '</p>';
        } 
        echo '</div>';  

        if(!empty($row['title'])) {
            echo'<h4><u>' . $row['title'] . ' in ' . $row['category'] . ' News Updates</u></h4>';
        }
        if(!empty($row['post'])) {
            echo '<pre><p class="">' . $row['post']. '</p></pre>';
        }
        echo '</div><br />'; 
    }
    echo'</div>';

?>
```